# Finding matching brackets with php/regex in longer texts

Tags: php, regex

I've tried to wrap my head around this for quite a while, but still haven't found a solution.

I'm working on some simple way of formatting, where I want some tags containing strings inside brackets, with the tag defined right before the bracket. The tags should be able to be inside other brackets too.

String:

```
This is some random text, tag1{while this is inside a tag2{tag}}. This is some
other text tag2{also with a tag  tag3{inside} of it}.
```

What I want to do now, is the content of each

```
tag1{}
tag2{}
tag3{}
```

I've found others with similar problems ([Find matching brackets using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300939/find-matching-brackets-using-regular-expression-in-php)) but their problem was more oriented on  how to find matching brackets inside of other brackets, while my problem is both that, and finding multiply brackets in a longer text.

Answer (score 3):

If the tags are always balanced, you could use an expression like this to get content and name of all tags, including nested tags.

```
\b(\w+)(?={((?:[^{}]+|{(?2)})*)})
```

[Example](http://ideone.com/DXJGr):

```
$str = "This is some random text, tag1{while this is inside a tag2{tag}}. This is some other text tag2{also with a tag  tag3{inside} of it}.";

$re = "/\\b(\\w+)(?={((?:[^{}]+|{(?2)})*)})/";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $m);

echo "* Tag names:\n";
print_r($m[1]);
echo "* Tag content:\n";
print_r($m[2]);
```

Output:

```
* Tag names:
Array
(
    [0] => tag1
    [1] => tag2
    [2] => tag2
    [3] => tag3
)
* Tag content:
Array
(
    [0] => while this is inside a tag2{tag}
    [1] => tag
    [2] => also with a tag  tag3{inside} of it
    [3] => inside
)
```

Comment: @cbuckley, both original expressions work. The first original one is shorter and nicer, but includes surrounding `{}` in the capture.

Comment: Agreed; I was just making the regex and the example consistent. Feel free to revert my change, or edit to mention both regexes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, if there is a regexp, that gets you all the inner and outer tags in one call, but you can use this regexp `/\{(([^\{\}]+)|(?R))*\}/` from the question you linked and iterate recursively into the results.

I added your tag name and some named sub patterns to the regexp for more clarity:

```
function search_tags($string, $recursion = 0) {
    $Results = array();
    if (preg_match_all("/(?<tagname>[\w]+)\{(?<content>(([^\{\}]+)|(?R))*)\}/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
        foreach ($matches as $match) {
            $Results[] = array('match' => $match[0], 'tagname' => $match['tagname'], 'content' => $match['content'], 'deepness' => $recursion);
            if ($InnerResults = search_tags($match['content'], $recursion+1)) {
                $Results = array_merge($Results, $InnerResults);
            }
        }
        return $Results;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This returns an array with all matches containing the whole match, the tag name, the content of the brackets and an *iteration counter*, showing you how often the match was nested inside other tags. I have added another level of nesting to your string for demonstration:

```
$text = "This is some random text, tag1{while this is inside a tag2{tag}}. This is some other text tag3{also with a tag tag4{and another nested tag5{inside}} of it}.";
echo '<pre>'.print_r(search_tags($text), true).'</pre>';
```

The output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [match] => tag1{while this is inside a tag2{tag}}
            [tagname] => tag1
            [content] => while this is inside a tag2{tag}
            [deepness] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [match] => tag2{tag}
            [tagname] => tag2
            [content] => tag
            [deepness] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [match] => tag3{also with a tag tag4{and another nested tag5{inside}} of it}
            [tagname] => tag3
            [content] => also with a tag tag4{and another nested tag5{inside}} of it
            [deepness] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [match] => tag4{and another nested tag5{inside}}
            [tagname] => tag4
            [content] => and another nested tag5{inside}
            [deepness] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [match] => tag5{inside}
            [tagname] => tag5
            [content] => inside
            [deepness] => 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

the regex it's this:

```
tag[0-9]+\{[^\}]+
```

and you should replace the inside tags first

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no other way. You need to loop over each bracket.

```
     $output=array();
     $pos=0;     
while(preg_match('/tag\d+\{/S',$input,$match,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE,$pos)){
   $start=$match[0][1];
   $pos=$offset=$start+strlen($match[0][0]);
   $bracket=1;
   while($bracket!==0 and preg_match('/\{|\}/S',$input,$found,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE,$offset)){
      ($found[0][0]==='}')?$bracket--:$bracket++;
      $offset=$found[0][1]+1;
   }
   $output[]=substr($input,$start,$offset-$start);
}
```